# Where can I find DMM probe sockets?

Tags: connector, design, multimeter

I am working on a DMM project and need sockets for standard probes. I don't even know what keywords to search for these. I could fallback and use banana sockets but it would be better if I could use the standard socket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most DMMs do use banana sockets (usually the [shrouded versions](http://uk.farnell.com/mc-multi-contact/23-3020-22/socket-4mm-shrouded-red-pk5/dp/1085482)), so these are what you are looking for.

[image]

Farnell has plenty of [options](http://uk.farnell.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=204065%20110049686%20110139471&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&skipManufacturer=false&skipParametricAttributeId=&prevNValues=204065%20110049686&mm=1000785%7C%7C,1002859%7C%7C,&filtersHidden=false&appliedHidden=false&autoApply=false&originalQueryURL=/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=204065&No=0&getResults=true&appliedparametrics=true&locale=en_UK&divisionLocale=en_UK&catalogId=&skipManufacturer=false&skipParametricAttributeId=&prevNValues=204065).

Comment: Bingo! I had no idea they were shrouded banana plugs!